Populate View Objects Programmatically
I am new to ADF and using JDeveloper 12.2.1.4.0.
I have the following use case.
I have a view object DepartmentVo defined on departments table(DepartmentEO) and have the REST API's exposed on it.
The REST URL of the resource will be like Dec12RestApp-RESTWebService-context-root/rest/1/DepartmentsResource?q=DepartmentId>25.
In the departments view object (DepartmentVo) I want to define an attribute(Ex:ChannelId) which I want to populate by querying another table(ex:channels) based on the value sent for query parameter DepartmentId.i.e value of 25 in the above example.
Please suggest on how I can achieve this use case.
Thanks,
